# duplicates getting printed on a binary search tree

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree

I want to implement a binary tree such that it does not include duplicates. Here's my insert() method.

```
public  BinaryNode insert(BinaryNode node, int x) {

    if (node == null) {
        node = new BinaryNode(x);
    } else if (x < node.element) {
        node.left = insert(node.left, x);
    } else if (node.element < x) {
        node.right = insert(node.right, x);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Duplicates not allowed");
        return null;
    }

    return node;
}


public static void main (String args[]) {
    BinaryTree t = new BinaryTree();
    t.root=t.insert(t.root, 5);
    t.insert(t.root, 6);
    t.insert(t.root, 4);
    t.insert(t.root, 60);
    t.insert(t.root, 25);
    t.insert(t.root, 10);
    t.insert(t.root, 10);
```

Why is the duplicate 10 get printed in this Binary tree. I thought `return null` in the else statement stops the recursion when a duplicate is found. When 10 is inserted again it prints out"Duplicates not allowed" but without stopping from there it goes on to add 10  a second time as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

**Remove the line `return null;` from the original code. This is the code you should be left with:**

```
public BinaryNode insert(BinaryNode node, int x) {

    if (node == null) {
        node = new BinaryNode(x);
    } else if (x < node.element) {
        node.left = insert(node.left, x);
    } else if (node.element < x) {
        node.right = insert(node.right, x);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Duplicates not allowed");
    }

    return node;
}
```

**Explanation:**

When you've added all the nodes, you have a tree looking like this:

```
        5
    4       6
                60
            25
        10
```

One problem with your code is that when facing a duplicate you return null. This code(called from node 25)

```
node.left = insert(node.left, x);
```

then get's this

```
node.left = null;
```

In other words; when you return null for duplicates, you erase the existing node. And as far as I can see, the new one isn't inserted. So in the case of a duplicate you just end up deleting the existing node. However, it will print "Duplicates not allowed".

**If you however drop `return null;`, the existing 10-node will be left as it is. And the new 10 will be ignored.**

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by " when you return null for duplicates, you erase the existing node.".You mean when I insert 10 again my eariler 10 is vanished? But when I am inserting 10 again (as the duplicate) none of the conditions in  if else clauses is satisfied. Because 10<10 and 10>10 are both not true. Therefore the only thing that satisfies is the else clause which tells to return a null object. So nothing should happen to the earlier nodes right?Isn't that what happens.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The else clause is used and returns `null`. But where is this `null` returned to? It's returned to `node.left = insert(node.left, x);` in the 25-node. So your 25-node's left-pointer will be set to null. And so, you are correct, your earlier 10 will vanish. But the new 10 is never inserted.

Comment: Thanks. Finally understood why my earlier 10 vanishes.Can you please explain what I can do to prevent duplicates being entered . how I can implement "Instead of returning null, you return the newly added node."I created a new BinaryNode as copy and at each if else I inserted the line  `copy=new BinaryNode(x);`.Then at else clause `return copy;`still 10 gets duplicated.

Comment: I initially implemented insert like that because this is the code given in lectures.`Private BinaryNode insert( Comparable x, BinaryNode t)
{if(t= = null)
t= new BinaryNode(x,null,null);
else if (x.compareTo(t.element)< 0 )
 t.left = insert(x, t.left);
else if (x.compareTo(t.element)> 0 )
t.right = insert(x, t.right);
Else
; // duplicate ; do nothing
return t;
}`

Comment: Haha, I can't believe I didn't see this yesterday. Just remove the line `return null;`. That should solve it. I've updated my answer to explain why =)

Answer (score 0):

the other post is correct as far as I can tell, but i suggest some changes.

first of all  - this line

`t.root=t.insert(t.root,5);`

should just be

```
t.insert(5);
```

an empty tree will be null on the first iteration of your recursive insert. your constructor should just be

```
BinaryTree t = new BinaryTree();
```

and your BinaryTree class should have a member Node variable as the root.